# Old Scheveningen beach play structure. What's it called?

Tags: beaches

Decades (sigh) ago I played with a permanent "one-person ferris wheel"-like structure on (I think) Scheveningen beach.  I consisted of two posts maybe 3 m tall and 1 m apart supporting a beam on an axle. On one end of this beam was a "hamster wheel" but fixed to the beam and on the other was a counter-weight. Everything was heavy galvanized steel and built to last.  There were several there.  I've never seen anything like them before or since.

The idea is to get into the wheel and by walking, change the center of gravity of the system and the whole thing would rotate, lifting the rider 4-5 m high.  I could get it going faster than I wanted to at the time.  :-)

What's it called?  Are there any left?

Comment: I think I remember those. But I don't think I ever saw them at Scheveningen. Perhaps at http://www.linnaeushof.nl/ ?

Comment: Hi @MastaBaba, that looks like a cool place! 
And it's contemporary (1965) but I was never there.  Maybe not Scheveningen, but definitely in the sand on the beach. 
Thanks. Doug.

Comment: How about drawing one and then asking Google for similar images?

Comment: I know the things, can't remember ever hearing a name for them. Haven't seen any in decades myself, they've probably fallen victim to the whole safety regulations thing that's swept the western world in the 1990s and beyond and left us so afraid of the least risk we're wary of heading out the front door without a protective suit.

Answer (score 2):

I (google helped a little :-) couldn't find the original but "we" found a two-person one used by Cirque Shanghai that I can use for design hints.
http://www.travelingmom.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Cirque-Shanghai-Wheel-of-Destiny-resize.jpg

Thanks for helping.
Doug